# Upgrade to WP 3.2/ and Server to php5 breaks theme?

Tags: theme-development, php, errors

I upgraded to Wordpress 3.2 and my server from php4 to php5 and now my site outputs this error;

**Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /homepages/35/d289582498/htdocs/wp-content/themes/NovatorixFullArchive_Version1.4/novatorix/index.php on line 98
Warning: getimagesize(http://itsadcoi.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/head1.png) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /homepages/35/d289582498/htdocs/wp-content/themes/NovatorixFullArchive_Version1.4/novatorix/index.php on line 98**

This is what's on line 98 as the error is stating; 
**list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($logo_url);**

How Can I fix it?

Comment: Did someone edit the WordPress core files on your site?

Comment: No, I just updated versions. It appears right above the top menu nav

Comment: I think this is too localized. It is a combination of PHP configuration (`allow_url_fopen`) and, likely, a poorly-coded Theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your theme compatible with the new version of WP? May be that it uses a deprecated function name somewhere.

But I've had updates go wrong previously.  The only thing that eventually sorted it out was to re-upload all the files of the new version using FTP, and overwriting what was there.  Won't have impact on your theme or other data, it just overwrites the core.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like a WordPress problem. There's a lot of sloppy PHP code out there that relied on security holes that were present in PHP4 but closed in PHP5, It sounds like your theme is using some of these - in particular URL file access, which was enabled by default in PHP4, and disabled by default in PHP5.

If you have access to the php.ini settings, you can change those settings. I believe the commands to use would be:

```
allow_url_fopen = 1;
allow_url_include = 1;
```

... but be sure you know what you're doing, from a security standpoint before making those changes.

A better fix would be just tweaking your theme to use the path to the image you're trying to get, rather than the url.

Comment: I think this is right, given the error message: **RL file-access is disabled in the server configuration**.